# Row level security returning no error when blocking all effects of a query

Tags: postgresql, permissions

With row level security enabled on `tbl`, but no policy set, as a user the `UPDATE` throws no error but does not modify the value:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = 1;
=> Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected
SELECT col FROM tbl;
=> NULL
```

If row level security is disabled on `tbl`, as a user:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = 1;
=> Query returned successfully: 1 row affected
SELECT col FROM tbl;
=> 1
```

I would expect to get something like: `ERROR: permission denied for relation tbl` instead of a kinda silent `0 rows affected`.

Can I get something more explicit?

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on CentOS 6.

**Edit:** Row level security is the cause, but I'm not clear why there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only enable RLS for a table, but do not specify rules, then a "deny all" rule is implicitly assumed.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html)

> When row security is enabled on a table [...] all normal access to the table for selecting rows or modifying rows must be allowed by a row security policy. [...] If no policy exists for the table, **a default-deny policy is used**, meaning that no rows are visible or can be modified.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So since the policy makes no rows visible, this is why there is no error when UPDATEing and you get `0 rows affected`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a **trigger** `ON UPDATE` that checks for the executing role and silently cancels the update for some, but not others:

Example:

```
...
IF pg_has_role('some_role', 'member') THEN
   RETURN NULL;
ELSE
   RETURN NEW;
END IF;
...
```

Related:

- [Allow insertion only from within a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151331/allow-insertion-only-from-within-a-trigger/20155754#20155754)

Comment: I have no triggers on this table. Row level security seems to be the cause. Edited.